# Are these alerts sent by Google or is my account compromised?

Tags: google-alerts

I have subscribed for Google Alerts email messages, but when I analysed a message's security details it says that it's mailed by "alerts.bounces.google.com", signed by: "google.com". Why is it mailed by "alerts.bounces.google.com"? Is this genuine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's normal. I looked back as far as January, 2016 in my collection of alert messages and the mail headers are the same.

I expect that they're trying to manage where bounce messages from invalid email addresses end up.